# Rename an array title in Firebase Firestore | Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a good way to rename an array's title in Swift? For example, I'd like to be able to change the array title "Cats" to "Dogs" (without it losing its values). I was updating the entire "Animals" dictionary, but surely there's a more efficient way to do this (update just the single sub-dictionary title).

*Dictionary setup:*

"**Animals**" (main dictionary)

-> Cats (sub-dictionary)

-> -> "Jimmy", "Lola", "Timmy" (cat names)

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
            print("The user is not signed into an account.")
            return
        }
        
        if userID.isEmpty != true {
            // Inside the "Animals" array, change the "Cats" dictionary title to "Dogs"
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific operation to rename a field, so you'll have to perform the operation by:

1. Reading the document to get the current array contents.
2. Writing the array with its new field name.
3. Remove the array from its old field name.